# Weblogic: JMS Create Message - Permissions

Tags: security, permissions, weblogic

My problem is this:

I need to create a JMS message in a JMS module with a user of Operators group but i don't know how add permissions to the group.

Create a message is possible with the admin user but i could not identify the correct permission.

What i can do?

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin console -> Security releams -> myrealms -> Realm roles -> Edit global role -> Roles ->  Goto Operator role -> Click view role conditions -> add the group whatever you want to give permission -> activate changes